# Using an example, show that $C$ does not have to be a field

Tags: probability, self-study

I’m reading *[A Probability Path](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/081764055X)* by S. Resnick, and I got stuck on one problem:

> **Problem 1.16** (*pp. 22-23*) Suppose $C$ is a class of subset of $\Omega$ such that  $\Omega \in C$, 
>   $A \in C $ implies that $A^c \in C$, and $C$ is closed under
>   *disjoint* unions. Using an example, show that $C$ does not have to be a field.

A hint is provided in book:

> Try $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $C$ be the field generated by two
>   point subsets of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hint actually takes you most way home.

Consider the collection 
$$
\mathscr{C} =\{\{1,2,3,4\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4\}, \{4,1\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,4\},\emptyset\}
$$

It is easy to see that this collection satisfies all the properties that are stated in the problem, but is not a field, for example, $\{1,2\}\cup \{2,3\}\notin \mathscr{C}$.

Comment: While the essence of this answer is correct, the concrete example given is not. If you were to remove *one* particular element from the class, then it would be correct.

Comment: Missed $\{2,4\}$ didn't I? Well-spotted.

Comment: Or, just remove $\{1,3\}$. It doesn't match the hint as closely, but has the virtue of being an even simpler example. (+1)

Comment: The "*hint*" as given in the question is kind of bogus anyway. I hope it's not written like that in the book.

Comment: @cardinal. This exactly how it is written in the book.

Comment: The Resnick book has excellent pedagogics -- I wouldn't be entirely surprised if this were deliberate.

Comment: I agree the Resnick book is, generally speaking, excellent. In this case, there was at least a minor slip-up in that it makes no sense to consider an example of a *field* $C$ when one is trying to prove that something is not a field. :)

Comment: @cardinal Precisely. ;)